# Error: "The drive is not ready for use; its door may be open."

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

On Windows Vista SP2 - I'm attempting to upgrade to Windows 7.

After I put in the Windows 7 DVD in the drive, I receive the Windows 7 upgrade splash screen (so the drive is working at this moment). But then when I click "Upgrade to Windows 7", I receive a error message stating:

Error:

```
The drive is not ready for use; its door may be open
```

Any ideas what's causing this error?

Since receiving the error, I have already replaced the DVD drive with a brand new one and still receive the same error.

I've also checked Device Manager and no hardware is reporting problems (no cautions or failures).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for your error but I can think of some alternative ways to install Windows 7 without using the CD.

1. You can copy all the Windows 7 installation files to another hard drive (if you have one) and install from there.  If you only have one drive you can partition it and the run the installation from the newly created partition
2. If you have a flash drive large enough you can create a bootable flash drive to install Windows 7.  [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) will perform all the steps you need to make your flash bootable.

Comment: What about a external harddrive that is connected via USB?  How would that work?

Comment: Yes you can. I believe the WinToFlash will work for a external USB hard drive too. If not see: http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/05/19/AR2009051902418.html

Comment: What's happens if I don't want to forgot my entire external USB harddrive to be bootable but simply a data directory?

Comment: You don't have to delete your files on there but you do have to copy all files and folders from the root of the Windows CD to the root of your HD

Answer (score 1):

This article doesn't exactly give you an answer but it's in the right direction.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222871

I wonder if your removable DVD drive on your laptop is not set to master (though I have no idea how to check).